# How to create a table from a .csv file?

Tags: r, import-from-csv

I have the following data from a .csv file:

```
Sp  Country   RMU           Temp    Males   Females 
Cc  Australia Pacific, S    25.00   0   7       
Cc  Australia Pacific, S    26.00   17  1   
Ei  STP       Atlantic, E   28.00   21  2       
Ei  Brazil    Atlantic, W   27.50   8   1
Nd  Australia Pacific, S    28.00   2   0
```

And I want to create a new table with Males values, just where "Sp==Cc", meaning

```
Males
0
17
```

I have tried this:

```
m=subset(file3_TMF, Sp=="Cc")$Males
```

but it is creating an "integer (empty)".

Can anyone help?

Comment: consider using dput to provide the data so that others can help you out more easily

Answer (score 0):

Those "," in the RMU field create a mess ... so using your data, assuming a .csv where on top of that you have the "," in between "Pacific , S":

1) scan file (read the csv file)
 2) unlist (outcome of scan is a list)
3) transform unlisted in a matrix with 8 columns (due to the   "," ahead of S/E/W)

```
> dat <- matrix(unlist(scan(file = "dat.csv", what = list(rep("character",8)),
                sep = ",", skip = 1)), ncol = 8, byrow = TRUE)
```

4) Subset rows where 1 column == "Cc", show Column 7 ("Male")

```
> dat[dat[,1] == "Cc",7]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `m=subset(file3_TMF, Sp=="Cc")$Males`, you have it a bit out of order.

It should be `subset(file3_TMF$Males, file3_TMF$Sp == "Cc")`

Any one of the following lines of code will also subset your data for `Males`, such that `Sp` is `Cc`.
The first two get you a subset of Male values, and the last returns all the rows of the original data for which `Sp == "Cc"`

Assume that `dat` is the name of your data.

```
> dat$Males[dat$Sp == "Cc"]
[1]  0 17

> dat[dat$Sp == "Cc", ]
  Sp   Country        RMU Temp Males Females
1 Cc Australia Pacific, S   25     0       7
2 Cc Australia Pacific, S   26    17       1
```